# How can I use the filter method on a React component prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, use-effect, react-props

I'm trying to filter through an array to pull out all the objects that match a specific month. I've passed the month in from the parent component, and when I console.log(month) it successfully returns 4 in this case.

Here's the beginning of my component:

```
const MonthlyIncome = ({incomeData, month}) => {

    useEffect(()=>{

        console.log(month)
        //returns 4
        console.log('income data', incomeData)

        if (month) {
            const incomes = incomeData?.filter(i=>{
                if(new Date(i?.date).getMonth() === month) {
                    return i
            }})
            console.log('incomes', incomes)
        }
        
    }, [])
```

The console.log('incomes', incomes) returns an empty array.

However, I can get it to successfully console.log the filtered array if I input a 4 directly into the useEffect instead of using month, like this:

```
const MonthlyIncome = ({incomeData, month}) => {

    
    useEffect(()=>{

        console.log(month)
        //returns 4
        console.log('income data', incomeData)

        if (month) {
            const incomes = incomeData?.filter(i=>{
                if(new Date(i?.date).getMonth() === 4) {
                    return i
            }})
            console.log('incomes', incomes)
        }
        
    }, [])
```

Does anyone know how I can properly pass in the month from the parent component into the filter() method?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, I guess the actual problem was that the number coming from the parent was a string, and I needed it to be an actual number.
So I used parseInt() to convert it from a string into a number like this:

```
const MonthlyIncome = ({incomeData, month}) => {

    
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(month)
        //returns 4
        console.log('income data', incomeData)

        const m = parseInt(month, 10)
       
        const incomes = incomeData?.filter(i=>{
            if(new Date(i?.date).getMonth() === m) {
                return i
        }})
        console.log('incomes', incomes)
        
        
    }, [])
```

Comment: I was just about to comment that it could be a type issue. Also note that you'll need to pass `incomeData` and `month` into the dependency array.